# Zooming an image on hover and not exceeding parent div borders

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a zoom effect using css3/html but for some reason I can't get the image to stay within the borders of the parent div.

I've tried nesting the image inside another div, and also just leaving it as just an image inside the parent div. It doesn't want to work for me.

Here's the current HTML

```
<div id="forumGroup" style="border: 1px solid #000000; box-shadow: 3px 3px  5px #999; border-radius: 10px; margin: 5px; display: block; width: 250px; height: 250px; padding: 10px; float: left; position: relative; text-align:  center; display: block;">
<div class="mainGroupImage">
<img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" style="width: 250px; height: 250px;" />
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.mainGroupImage{
max-width: 100%;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
-moz-transition: all 1s ease; /* Firefox */
-ms-transition: all 1s ease; /* IE 9 */
-o-transition: all 1s ease; /* Opera */
transition: all 1s ease;
}

.mainGroupImage:hover{
-webkit-transform:scale(1.25); /* Safari and Chrome */
-moz-transform:scale(1.25); /* Firefox */
-ms-transform:scale(1.25); /* IE 9 */
-o-transform:scale(1.25); /* Opera */
 transform:scale(1.25);
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ojc5aaaf/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add the following style to your containing `#forumGroup` div so that is doesn't allow the inner contents to exceed its boundaries.

```css
#forumGroup{
  overflow:hidden
}

.mainGroupImage{
  max-width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease; /* Firefox */
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease; /* IE 9 */
  -o-transition: all 1s ease; /* Opera */
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.mainGroupImage:hover{
  -webkit-transform:scale(1.25); /* Safari and Chrome */
  -moz-transform:scale(1.25); /* Firefox */
  -ms-transform:scale(1.25); /* IE 9 */
  -o-transform:scale(1.25); /* Opera */
   transform:scale(1.25);
}
```

```html
<div id="forumGroup" style="border: 1px solid #000000; box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #999; border-radius: 10px; margin: 5px; display: block; width: 250px; height: 250px; padding: 10px; float: left;                 position: relative; text-align: center; display: block;">
  <div class="mainGroupImage">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" style="width: 250px; height: 250px;" />
  </div>
</div>
```

This will still allow the zoom factor, but it will stay "within" the rounded radius.

Also, I know this is probably just test code, but go ahead and put the `#forumGroup` styles inside of the stylesheet as well (not inline). :)

Comment: You may need `transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` on `#forumGroup`.  There's a bug at least in Chrome on Mac that causes the border radius and overflow hidden to not be respected  during the CSS transition.  Adding the translate3d rule is a work around that forces GPU rendering I believe.

Comment: Thanks, simple solution. Works perfect. And yes, it is just test code. I will be moving it the stylesheet before launch. 

Edit: I'll add the transform and test it on a mac here at work.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue on a recent project and I had a simple solution.

I added

```
overflow: hidden;
```

to the parent div and it solved the problemm.